# Why does assignment using await within while expression not retain assigned value?

Tags: javascript, while-loop, ecmascript-6, async-await, ecmascript-next

Given the JavaScript code

```js
function* gen(start = 0, stop = 5) {
   while (start < stop) yield ++start;
}

async function fn(g = gen()) {
  while (done = !await new Promise(resolve => 
                   setTimeout(resolve, 1000, g.next()))
                   .then(({value, done}) => {
                     // `value:undefined, done:true` following
                     // `value:5, done:false`
                     console.log(`value:${value}, done:${done}`); 
                     return done 
                   }
                   , err => Promise.reject(err)));
  return done; // what happened to the `true` value assigned?
}
// why is `res` `false`?
fn().then(res => console.log(`res:${res}`), err => console.error(err));
```

the expected result of `done` returned from `fn()` is `true` when `done` is assigned the value `true` that is returned from `.then()` within `while` expression.

Why is the assignment using [`await`](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-async-function-definitions) at [`while`](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-while-statement) statement [expression](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#prod-Expression) not retained?

Comment: "why is res false" ... because the while loop will continue until `!await new Promise(resolve => ....` is false ... at which point, done === false, which is what `fn` will return

Comment: @JaromandaX `!await new Promise(resolve => ....` is evaluated to `false` at `while` expression when `true` is returned when `value:undefined, done:true`, as evidenced by `value: true` logged at `console`, though the assigned value is not retained.

Comment: fn() will only ever return true ... don't need to knwo anything about the dogs breakfast inside the "condition"

Comment: @JaromandaX Using a `do..while` loop returns expected result. The question is why is the `true` returned from `.then()` at last iteration using `await` assignment is not retained following `while` loop?

Comment: `fn().then(res =>` with the question `why is res false` ... the reason is, that `fn()` will always ever only ever return a Promise that resolves to false, ever, never anything else, don't even need to read the 259 characters after the ! ... `while done = !.... all this is irrelevant ....);` means that the only exit is when `done === false`, which is what the function returns after the loop

Comment: @JaromandaX Was inverting the boolean at the incorrect location `let done;
  while ((done = await new Promise(resolve => 
                   setTimeout(resolve, 1000, g.next()))
                   .then(({value, done}) => {console.log(value, done); return !done}
                   , err => Promise.reject(err))));
  return !done;`

Comment: my comments were about the code in the question and explaining why it was always false ... of course different code will produce different results ... like answering "why isn't 1 + 1 = 3" ... with "if you change that to 1 + 2, that will = 3" ... whereas my comment was "because 1 + 1 is 2"

Comment: @JaromandaX  _"my comments were about the code in the question and explaining why it was always false"_ Can you post an Answer including your description of the reason for the resulting value?

Comment: no, because I haven't bothered reading the 259 characters between `!` and `);` to even care what the code is attempting to achieve

Comment: @JaromandaX You already stated that that portion of code is irrelevant and doubled down on your strict interpretation and reason for the result _"`while done = !.... all this is irrelevant ....);` means that the only exit is when done === false, which is what the function returns after the loop"_ Why do you not formalize your evaluation of the code as an Answer? The code is attempting to ascertain the limits of expectations as to variable assignment using `await`.

Comment: because I don't care

Comment: @JaromandaX What does caring have to do with anything? Did not ask for your emotion, but rather for your formal answer to a question.

Comment: look ... it's clear that done will always be returned as a Promise of `false` in that code - how can you make it `true`? well, you could `return !done` - but that doesn't address any of the 259 characters of code that I haven't bothered with ... returning `!done` ... will return the expected result, but how does that relate to the 259 characters? I simply don't know, and don't wish to analyse it, which is why I made a comment, rather than post an answer in the first place

Comment: @JaromandaX Your comments answered the question nonetheless.

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript has "three" different types of scope: local, global, and block.

**Global**

This type of variable can be reach in all places of the code:

```
var b = "bar";
   (function test1(a) {
         if (a == true) {
              var b = "bar";
         } else {
              var b = "foo";
         }
         return b;
    })(true);
    alert(b);
```

**Local**

These variables can only be reached if the variable in the general scope of the code:

```
(function test2(a) {
     if (a == true) {
          var b = "bar";
     } else {
          var b = "foo";
     }
     return b;
})(true)
```

In this case, the general scope is the function. Even though the variable `b` is block scoped by the if statement, the function can still reach it.

**Block**

Self defined block scoped variables are pretty new to JavaScript and can be introduced using the `let` keyword:

```
(function test2(a) {
     if (a == true) {
          let b = "bar";
     } else {
          let b = "foo";
     }
     return b;
})(true)
```

This will result in an error because the variable `b` is now block scoped to the if state. Thus in your code, we can change your scoping to allow you to change done which in a while loop is block scoped in the case of asynchronous loops.

```
function* gen(start = 0, stop = 5) {
   while (start < stop) yield ++start;
}

async function fn(g = gen()) {
  let doneVal;
  while (done = !await new Promise(resolve => 
                   setTimeout(resolve, 1000, g.next()))
                   .then(({value, done}) => {
                     // `value:undefined, done:true` following
                     // `value:5, done:false`
                     console.log(`value:${value}, done:${done}`); 
                     return done 
                   }
                   , err => Promise.reject(err))) {
       doneVal = done;
  }

  return doneVal; // what happened to the `true` value assigned?
}
// why is `res` `false`?
fn().then(res => console.log(`res:${res}`), err => console.error(err));
```

Now you will get `res:true`. In your specific example, there is an issue with code like this:

```
var i;
var c = 0;
while (i = 90 && c < 10) {
    c++;
}
console.log(i, c);
```

`i` is false while `c` is equal to 10

Comment: Function parameter `(a, b)` has own scope as well, yes?

Comment: The parameters are locally scoped to the function.

Comment: Why is the `true` returned from `.then()` not retained as the value of `done`?

Comment: It seems as loops scope using block scope. The value is retained. But does to scoping you can't see it by the way you wrote it. Check out this example: https://jsfiddle.net/dpry01ca/

Comment: The expression can used without the statement by inverting the return value from `.then()` and the value returned from `fn()` `while ((done = await new Promise(resolve => 
                   setTimeout(resolve, 1000, g.next()))
                   .then(({value, done}) => {console.log(value, done); return !done}
                   , err => Promise.reject(err))));
  return !done;`

Comment: Thats is what I use noticed. You use `await` so it will also give you false

Comment: The code at Question does not use the statement option of `while`

Comment: But you are using fn() while still uses the while loop

Answer (score 1):

The comments by @JaromandaX helped recognize that the `!` was not in correct place within code to return expected result. The Answer by @Shawn31313 reminded to define variable using parameter or `let` within function call, as `done` being defined as a global variable was not intended

```js
function* gen(start = 0, stop = 5) {
   while (start < stop) {
     yield ++start;
   }
}
async function fn(g = gen()) {
  let done;
  while ((done = await new Promise(resolve => 
                   setTimeout(resolve, 1000, g.next()))
                   .then(({value, done}) => {
                     console.log(value, done); 
                     return !done
                   }
                   , err => Promise.reject(err))));
  return !done;
}

fn().then(res => console.log(res), err => console.error(err));
```

Comment: Btw, you really should just use `for (let value of g) { await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 1000)); console.log(value, false); } return true`

Comment: @Bergi That is not the gist of the Question