# Wrap a resultset callback function with a generator/iterator

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I'm working on converting a legacy callback-based API into an async library. But I just can't wrap my head around getting a "resultset" to work as a generator (Node 10.x).

The original API works like this:

```js
api.prepare((err, rs) => {
    rs.fetchRows(
        (err, row) => {
            // this callback is called as many times as rows exist
            console.log("here's a row:", row);
        },
        () => {
            console.log("we're done, data exausted");
        }
    );
});
```

But here is how I want to use it:

```js
const wrapped = new ApiWrapper(api);
const rs = await wrapped.prepare({});
for (let row of rs.rows()) {
    console.log("here's a row:", row);
}

let row;
while(row = await rs.next()) {
    console.log("here's a row:", row);
}
```

I thought I had it under control with generators, but it looks like you cannot use `yield` inside a callback. It actually seems logical if you think about.

```js
class ApiWrapper {
    constructor(api) {
        this.api = api;
    }
    prepare() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this.api.prepare((err, rs) => {
                if (err) {
                    reject(err);
                } else {
                    resolve(rs);
                }
            });
        });
    }
    *rows() {
        this.api.fetchRows((err, row) => {
            if (err) {
                throw err;
            } else {
                yield row; // nope, not allowed here
            }
        });
    }
    next() { ... }
}
```

So what alternatives do I have?

**Important**: I don't want to store anything in an array then iterate that, we're talking giga-loads of row data here.

**Edit**
I'm able to simulate the behavior I want using `stream.Readable` but it warns me that it's an experimental feature. Here's a simplified array-based version of the issue I'm trying to solve using `stream`:

```js
const stream = require('stream');
function gen(){
    const s = new stream.Readable({
        objectMode: true,
        read(){
            [11, 22, 33].forEach(row => {
                this.push({ value: row });
            });
            this.push(null)
        }
    });
    return s;
}

for await (let row of gen()) {
    console.log(row);
}

// { value: 11 }
// { value: 22 }
// { value: 33 }

(node:97157) ExperimentalWarning: Readable[Symbol.asyncIterator] is an experimental feature. This feature could change at any time
```

Comment: Generators are not asynchronous. Are you looking for an [AsyncIterator](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-async-iteration/blob/master/README.md)?

Comment: Not sure, but it could work. I'll take a look, thanks.

Comment: AsyncIterator is probably the way to go, but I still can't understand how to return either iterator or generator from within a callback. I need something like an iterateable `Promise` that can be fulfilled for each row of data that arrives into the callback. The close I can get to this is by returning a stream (they are iterable) that gets rows pushed into with every callback.

Comment: Each `next` call of the iterator needs to create a promise for the next row - you will probably need to create a queue of resolvers for this.

Comment: @ojosilva _"But here is how I want to use it:"_ Are you trying to do something like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/47172222/? Or https://stackoverflow.com/a/48349837/?

Comment: I think I've found the answer, with what @bergi said about "queue" I attempted a queue implementation which did not work then realized I needed something like Go's channels that would work with async/await. This wonderful module did it: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nodeguy/channel. I'll post the answer soon.

Answer (score 1):

I finally realized I needed something similar to Go's channels that were `async/await` compatible. Basically the answer is to synchronize an async iterator and a callback, making them wait for each other as `next()` iterations are consumed.

The best (Node) *native* solution I found was to use a `stream` as an iterator, which is supported in Node 10.x but tagged experimental. I also tried to implement it with the `p-defer` NPM module, but that turned out to be more involved than I expected. Finally ran across the https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nodeguy/channel module, which was exactly what I needed:

```js
const Channel = require('@nodeguy/channel');

class ApiWrapper {
    // ...
    rows() {
        const channel = new Channel();
        const iter = {
            [Symbol.asyncIterator]() {
                return this;
            },
            async next() {
                const val = await channel.shift();
                if (val === undefined) {
                    return { done: true };
                } else {
                    return { done: false, value: val };
                }
            }
        };

        this.api.fetchRows(async (err, row) => {
            await channel.push(row);
        }).then(() => channel.close());

        return iter;
    }
}

// then later

for await (let row of rs.rows()) {
     console.log(row)
}
```

Note how each iterating function core, `next()` and `rows()`, have a `await` that will throttle how much data can be pushed across the channel, otherwise the producing callback could end up pushing data uncontrollably into the channel queue. The idea is that the callback should wait for data to be consumed by the iterator `next()` before pushing more.

Here's a more self-contained example:

```js
const Channel = require('@nodeguy/channel');

function iterating() {
    const channel = Channel();

    const iter = {
        [Symbol.asyncIterator]() {
            return this;
        },
        async next() {
            console.log('next');
            const val = await channel.shift();
            if (val === undefined) {
                return { done: true };
            } else {
                return { done: false, value: val };
            }
        }
    };

    [11, 22, 33].forEach(async it => {
        await channel.push(it);
        console.log('pushed', it);
    });

    console.log('returned');
    return iter;
}

(async function main() {
    for await (let it of iterating()) {
        console.log('got', it);
    }
})();

/*
returned
next
pushed 11
got 11
next
pushed 22
got 22
next
pushed 33
got 33
next
*/
```

Like I said, Streams and/or Promises can be used to implement this, but the `Channel` module solves some of the complexity that make it more intuitive.

Comment: I don't think `await`ing the `channel.push(…)` call makes sense, neither in the `fetchRows` nor the `forEach` callback. Both will ignore any promise returned by the callback, they don't support backpressure.

Comment: The `await` in `channel.push()` in `fetchRows` guarantees that `next()` processes the results in the *same order*. It also protects against backpressure if the callback caller awaits for the callback response. In the `forEach()` just scroll to the output below the code to see it working synchronously. If you remove the `await` in the `forEach()`, the array items will be pushed to the channel on the first go, then the iterator will run.

Comment: "*if the callback caller awaits for the callback response*" - yes, only iff the caller does that. But `fetchRows` doesn't appear to be promise-aware. (If it was, you could implement the async iterator much easier than with that channel). And no, it's not relevant for order.

Comment: "*If you remove the `await` in the `forEach()`, the array items will be pushed to the channel on the first go*" - they always are, because `forEach` ignores the promise and synchronously iterates the array. The only difference is that `await` causes the "pushed it" logs to be asynchronous - the `push()` calls themselves happen immediately. Try logging "going to push" before the `push()` call. You can simulate actual backpressure with `for await (const x of iterating()) {  await new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, 100)); console.log('got', x); }`.

Comment: You're right, they are being loaded into a data structure inside the channel. So back to square one... It's incredible how hard this is when callbacks, iterators, generators and streams are all present in the language and should be trivial to convert a callback into an iteration without queuing them in memory.

Comment: If `fetchRows` is asynchronous (doesn't make all callback calls at once), then the channel is entirely appropriate and without backpressure, you should be able to expect the queue to hold at most a single item at a time. If `fetchRows` doesn't support any kind of backpressure, then you cannot do it without queuing in memory at all. Yes, converting internal iteration to an external iterator is hard...

Comment: I guess the correct answer would be to use a `Readable()` stream as an iterator source. `reader = new Readable({ objectMode: true, read(){} }); process.nextTick( () => [...].forEach(it => reader.push(it) ) ); for await ( let it of reader ) { ... }` handles backpressure correctly by only pushing when ready and the only issue remaining is that it's experimental

Answer (score 0):

The original question has two nested callback taking async functions

- `api.prepare((err,res) => ...)`
- `rs.fetchRows((err,res) => ...)`

The first one runs the callback only once so just promisifying it as follows is sufficient.

```
function promisfied(f){
  return new Promise((v,x) => f(x,v));
}
```

However the second function will invoke it's callback multiple times and we wish to generate an async iterable from this function such that we can consume it in a `for await of` loop.

This is also possible by employing async generators as follows;

```
async function* rowEmitterGenerator(rs){
  let _v, // previous resolve
      _x, // previous reject
      _row = new Promise((v,x) => (_v = v, _x = x));
  rs.fetchRows((err, row) => ( err ? _x(err) : _v(row)
                             , _row = new Promise((v,x) => (_v = v, _x = x))
                             ));
  while(true){
    try {
      yield _row;
    }
    catch(e){
      console.log(e);
    }
  }
}
```

Then putting all together in a top level await context;

```
const rows       = await promisified(api.prepare),
      rowEmitter = rowEmitterGenerator(rows);

for await (let row of rowEmitter){
  console.log(`Received row: ${row}`);
  // do something with the row
}
```