# Infinite async loops using setInterval()

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have nodejs app that needs a few infinite loops which call async functions. I was considering implementing the following:

```
async function execute1() {
   ...do some async work...
}

async function execute2() {
   ...do some async work...
}

setInterval(execute1, 500)
setInterval(execute2, 500)
```

My concern is that if the async functions will take a long time to complete, the open references will pile up and this can result in a memory crash down the line.

1. is setInterval the right tool for this job? is there a more suitable tool?
2. What is the most elegant method to make sure the execute() function will not start if the previous run hasn't return?

Comment: you need to `await` those async events

Comment: You could `setTimerOut()` within the call, once it completes it will call itself.

Comment: _"I have nodejs app that needs a few infinite loops"_ Why are infinite loops needed? Why is `setInterval()` needed?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`setInterval` isn't the right tool because it's unaware of promises and can't maintain correct control flow.

It can be `async` function with infinite loop:

```
async function execute1() {
  while (true) {
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 500));
    // ...do some async work...  
  }
}

execute1();
```

Comment: How to `break` out of the `while` loop?

Comment: @guest271314 By using a condition instead of `true`.

Comment: FWIW One pattern that used for a condition to achieve breaking the loop `let done; while ((done = await new Promise(resolve => ..}).then(() => return !done})))` [Why does assignment using await within while expression not retain assigned value?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47172222/). And a verbose approach based on the former pattern [Run multiple recursive Promises and break when requested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48349837/2801559)

Answer (score 4):

`setTimeout` might work better in this case.

```
async function execute1(delay) {
   // await ...
   setTimeout(() => execute1(delay), delay)
}
execute1(500)
```

Comment: @messerbill — No, it won't. The answer completely fails to explain how this approach works, but it will run repeatedly.

Comment: It will execute once, then call setTimeout to execute again, and then again & again, ...

Comment: omg...i missed the call to itself, only read `setTimeout`....nvm

Answer (score 1):

you can use simple flags to indicate whether the previous function is still running

```
let isRunning = false;

async function execute1() {
   if (isRunning) return;
   isRunning = true

   ...do some async work...

   // make sure to call this whether it succeeds or fails, maybe in a finally block
   isRunning = false
}

setInterval(execute1, 500)
```

Comment: Fair, but I think the setTimeout it likely the easier solution for this one.

Comment: May not be obvious to some but if `...do some async work...` does not contain any `await` statements, the `if (isRunning)` will never execute when `isRunning === true`.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function that will run your `execute1()`, then wait for it's completion, then run itself with `setTimeout()`.

```js
function randomSleep() {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, Math.random() * 3000));
}

let done = 0;

async function execute1() {
   console.log('Execute 1 started.')
   await randomSleep()
   return 'done'
}

const run = () => {
  execute1().then(result => {
    console.log('Execute 1 ended')
    done++
    console.log(`Done ${done} times.`)
    console.log(`Now waiting for 2 seconds`)
    setTimeout(() => {
      run()
    }, 2000)
  })
}

run()
```

Comment: Tested this in node.js. Shouldn't it work withour the randomSleep part? When removing that part this does not wait for the execute1() to finish.